# CodeIgniter What does it mean to load multiple views?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
    class Page extends CI_Controller
    {
        function index()
        {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('menu');
            $this->load->view('content', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to run this example. However, only page faults are generated and not executed. I am curious about these things.

1. Does this example have header, menu, content, and footer in one view page?
2. I want to run this example but how do I write it? Should I create another ViewPage?

Comment: you need to create views in `application/view` folder

Comment: you have to create `application/view` and create those 4 pages.

Comment: The view folder has already been created.

Comment: Yes @최느님 Views is default folder of Codeigniter. You have to create 4 file in it. like 
- header.php
- menu.php
- content.php //content page
- footer.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Codeigniter then view function call the pages inside your view folder. The name you have to give is without the php extension. for example you folder structure look something like this

```
->view
 -header.php //have the header section
 -menu.php //menu for the website
 -content.php //page content
 -footer.php //footer files
```

So when you load these view in your controller with proper order it will give you a complete web page. 
I learned CodeIgniter from this [tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) Which is from the CodeIgniter itself. If you go through this you will get the idea how CodeIgniter works.

Comment: We've successfully solved your issue with your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome, if it helps give a vote up or if this the appropriate solution give a green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [Merge Bootstrap to your current codeIgniter project in PhpStorm on ubuntu 16.04](http://shyamaligunawardhana.blogspot.com/2017/03/merge-bootstrap-to-your-current.html) blog post. At the end of the post, it has described how to add header footer to your site step by step

Answer (score 1):

The example given by you is an approach that define the `Master Page` kind of thing in which the page is divided into different parts and the content section is the area which changes when the page changes and rest all remains the same.

here `header`, `menu`, `footer`, `content` these are different views. All these section remains same for all the pages. But `content` is the page that contains the actual data in it, which is different for each page.

`$this->load->view('content', $data);`

So we are passing the `$data` variable in it.

Comment: I do not know what it means to access the master page.

Comment: https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000600107-Master-pages-and-page-layouts

Comment: **We've successfully solved your issue** ? I think the issue is your's, not mine?

Comment: It also includes the part that you had a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Like Pranav says...

In application/view create a file called header.php

You can put your header html in there.

Repeat for the other views.

The $data variable in the example gets passed to the content view.

```
$data['my_paragraph'] = 'Here is all my content';
```

so application/view/content.php could be written like:

```
<div>
  <?=$my_paragraph?>
</div>
```

Comment: Just create a header page?

Comment: Yeah...  header.php
It could contain <html> and then your footer page could contain </html>
You'd probably want it to be a bit more than that so it would actually contain your header, but easy to start simple and build up.

Comment: We've successfully solved your issue with your help. Thank you very much.